# How to create an increasing color of background for 3 cells in one row?

Tags: background-image, xsl-fo

I would like to create this kind of background in my xsl-fo document:

[image: Gradually increasing color for background]

I blurred out the sensitive info, but hopefully it is still visible enough that it should be a grey color that gets increased from cell to cell.

This is my code behind it:

```
<!-- table header -->
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell margin-left="55pt" padding-after="10pt">
                            <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="boldtext">
                                <fo:block>
                                   1st column header
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="30pt" padding-after="10pt">
                            <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="boldtext">
                                <fo:block>
                                     2nd column header
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="15pt" padding-after="10pt">
                            <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="boldtext">
                                <fo:block>
                                     3rd column header
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
```

Comment: Create an SVG that is the triangle and use behind the table. If you want it broken like that, use a white border on the middle cell left and right.

Answer (score 1):

If you use RenderX you could use their extensions to scale background images. This solution would be like this. It would scale completely to the table with the number of rows and/or the size. It is unclear in your example what else would be in the table.

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" background-image="tri.svg" background-position="bottom left" background-repeat="no-repeat" rx:background-content-width="scale-to-fit" rx:background-content-height="scale-to-fit" rx:background-scaling="non-uniform">
            <fo:table-body >
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                1st column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="5pt solid white" border-right="5pt solid white">
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                2nd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                3rd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                1st column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="5pt solid white" border-right="5pt solid white">
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                2nd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                3rd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                1st column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="5pt solid white" border-right="5pt solid white">
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                2nd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                3rd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                1st column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="5pt solid white" border-right="5pt solid white">
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                2nd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                3rd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                1st column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="5pt solid white" border-right="5pt solid white">
                        <fo:block-container >
                            <fo:block>
                                2nd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block>
                                3rd column header
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

This results in this:

[image]

If you are using FOP, it is not clear to me that such extensions exist and you would likely need to size the SVG for the table if known.

Comment: Kevin, maybe I don't understand it, because i'm new to this, sorry for that. I just wanted to let you or the next person to know what was the exact code that worked for me (because just by copy and paste, it did not give me the result I needed!), and I cannot enter my code in a comment. But next time I will not do it then.

Comment: @Meredydd You should be able to accept the answer (green check mark). You asked the question so there are two things -- upvoting a useful answer and accepting an answer. If you wish to then add additional information that is useful you can in comments or even edit your question your specific edits to the answer.